# What causes the "Failed to create the hard disk storage" error when creating a new virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox

This is the error I received:

> Failed to create the hard disk storage C:\Users\Sara\VirtualBox VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd.
>
> Could not create the medium storage unit 'C:\Users\Sara\VirtualBox VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd'.
>
> VHD: cannot set the file size for 'C:\Users\Sara\VirtualBox VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd' (VERR_DISK_FULL).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
>   Component: Medium
>   Interface: IMedium {53f9cc0c-e0fd-40a5-a404-a7a5272082cd}

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have enough disk space to make the virtual hard drive you were trying to make.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error code `VERR_DISK_FULL` sums it up.  Your disk is full.  Free up some space and it should work.

Comment: Alternatively, decrease the size of your VHD.

Comment: Decreasing the size of the virtual disk will work if it isn't a dynamically growable disk file.  If it is dynamically growable, it's already as small as it can be.