# How to resize virtualbox guest storage which is splited

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, resizing

My host is windows 10 and guest is Mint 19 cinnamon 64 bit. When I made this guest I selected my storage size 100 GB, formate VMDK, and split the file in 2 GB. So now I have many .vmdk files such as mint19.vmdk,  mint19-s001.vmdk, mint19-s002.vmdk ...... mint19-s0051.vmdk.

Now I would like to resize this to 150 GB. I found many links online. But no link about the split vmdk. Perhaps according to online forum vmdk needs to be converted to vdi format. By the following command:-

```
vboxmanage clonehd mint19.vmdk "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --format vdi
```

I tired. It failed by the following output:

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to clone medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the clone medium 'C:\Users\eluihsm\VirtualBox VMs\mint19\new-virtualdisk.vdi' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCloneMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 990 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

For another try, I try to use one first split file as:

```
vboxmanage clonehd  mint19-s001.vmdk "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --format vdi
```

It failed immediately. With the following error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\eluihsm\VirtualBox VMs\mint19\mint19-s001.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

Also, I tried as admin console and nonadmin console. The same result. Of course, my guest was shut down while trying this process.

So how to resize my storage from 100 GB to 150GB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the "Failed to create the hard disk storage" error when creating a new virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/454039/what-causes-the-failed-to-create-the-hard-disk-storage-error-when-creating-a-n)

Comment: You understand this process creates a clone, so not only do you need the space for the original copy, but you need space for the new copy.  `VERR_DISK_FULL`  indicates the physical disk you are trying to create the virtual HDD is full. Any command you perform must be done on `mint19.vmdk`

Comment: After you make room for the new clone on your disk, you should also use `--format VMDK` instead of `--format vdi`, no reason to use `--format vdi` in a case like this

Comment: @masiboo Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @Jake Actually, my laptop SSD had not enough space to resize the vm disk. So I managed externally  2 TB HDD. And did overcome this error.